# Crash when using cupsfilter, no crash when printing normally (Zebra ZC400)

Tags: printing

I'm trying to produce a raw output that I can send as raw to my Zebra ZC400 as follows :

```
$ cupsfilter -e -p zebra4pihyve.ppd -m printer/Zebra ~/Bureau/test.pdf
```

Full results here : [link](https://pastebin.com/8ftXaqEP)

However it seems that it crashes when calling the last filter.

I have tried to do it in several steps :

```
cupsfilter -e -p zebra4pihyve.ppd -m application/vnd.cups-raster ~/Bureau/test.pdf > out
```

--> works

```
cupsfilter -e -p zebra4pihyve.ppd -i application/vnd.cups-raster -m printer/foo out > out2

-> crashes
(what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid
ERROR: /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertojg (PID 30461) crashed on signal 6)
```

Here is the list of the filters involved

```
$ cupsfilter -e -p zebra4pihyve.ppd -m printer/foo ~/Bureau/test.pdf --list-filters
cupsfilter: File "/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertojg" permissions OK (0100755/uid=0/gid=0).
cupsfilter: File "/usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftojgpdf" permissions OK (0100755/uid=0/gid=0).
pdftojgpdf
pdftopdf
gstoraster
/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertojg
```

Now what I don't understand is that I have not problem printing to this printer and don't understand.

How the **normal** cups pipeline is different from what I do with cups-filter?

I would really appreciate it if someone could give me a hint ;-)

Best regards.